# Apache 2.2 on CentOS 5.5 doesn't serve PHP files after upgrade to php53

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, httpd, php5

I just upgraded a CentOS 5.5 server (using Apache 2.2) to PHP53 (using the `php53u` set of packages).

All of a sudden, Apache doesn't appear to recognize `.php` files. It's just delivering the source.

Please help! I need to get this server back online as soon as possible.

Comment: I believe CentOS 5.6 has native php53 packages. Why didn't you update to 5.6 and use those?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this exact issue was addressed on StackOverflow: [Issues installing PHP 5.3 with apache on centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302027/issues-installing-php-5-3-with-apache-on-centos).  In a nutshell:

```
yum install yum-priorities
yum remove php php-*
yum remove httpd 
yum install httpd 
yum install php53u-pear php53u php53u-cli php53u-common php53u-devel php53u-gd php53u-mbstring php53u-mcrypt php53u-mysql php53u-pdo php53u-soap php53u-xml php53u-xmlrpc php53u-bcmath php53u-pecl-apc php53u-pecl-memcache php53u-snmp
yum remove php53u-pecl-apc
yum update php53u-pecl-apc --enablerepo=ius-testing
service httpd restart
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the post above - I found that post before I posted this one, followed the steps exactly, and still didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that (at least on my installation of CentOS) an upgrade to php53 updates `/etc/php.ini` with:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

so if your php scripts use the `<? .. ?>` syntax, you should change it back to:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Worked for me :)